# om.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile jsp files

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy a sample app in the Google app engine.
It is working fine locally but i am getting this error while deploying in app engine.
Below is the log. Any help is appreciated....

```
Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: '/tmp/appcfg2293558534073477148.tmp'
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Compiling jsp files.
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile jsp files.
Nov 5, 2012 8:43:06 AM org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler generateClass
SEVERE: Error compiling file: /tmp/appcfg2293558534073477148.tmp/WEB-    INF/classes/org/apache/jsp/pages/list_jsp.java     [javac] Compiling 1 source file
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 1. WARNING in /tmp/appcfg2293558534073477148.tmp/WEB-    INF/classes/org/apache/jsp/pages/list_jsp.java (at line 7)
    [javac]     public final class list_jsp extends org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase
    [javac]                        ^^^^^^^^
    [javac] The serializable class list_jsp does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 2. WARNING in /tmp/appcfg2293558534073477148.tmp/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/jsp/pages/list_jsp.java (at line 14)
    [javac]     private javax.el.ExpressionFactory _el_expressionfactory;
    [javac]                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] The field list_jsp._el_expressionfactory is never read locally
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 3. WARNING in /tmp/appcfg2293558534073477148.tmp/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/jsp/pages/list_jsp.java (at line 15)
    [javac]     private org.apache.AnnotationProcessor _jsp_annotationprocessor;
    [javac]                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] The field list_jsp._jsp_annotationprocessor is never read locally
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 4. ERROR in /tmp/appcfg2293558534073477148.tmp/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/jsp/pages/list_jsp.java (at line 17)
    [javac]     public Object getDependants() {
    [javac]                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] The return type is incompatible with JspSourceDependent.getDependants()
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 5. ERROR in /tmp/appcfg2293558534073477148.tmp/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/jsp/pages/list_jsp.java (at line 22)
    [javac]     _el_expressionfactory = _jspxFactory.getJspApplicationContext(getServletConfig().getServletContext()).getExpressionFactory();
    [javac]                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 6. WARNING in /tmp/appcfg2293558534073477148.tmp/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/jsp/pages/list_jsp.java (at line 33)
    [javac]     HttpSession session = null;
    [javac]                 ^^^^^^^
    [javac] The local variable session is never read
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 7. WARNING in /tmp/appcfg2293558534073477148.tmp/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/jsp/pages/list_jsp.java (at line 34)
    [javac]     ServletContext application = null;
    [javac]                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] The local variable application is never read
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 8. WARNING in /tmp/appcfg2293558534073477148.tmp/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/jsp/pages/list_jsp.java (at line 35)
    [javac]     ServletConfig config = null;
    [javac]                   ^^^^^^
    [javac] The local variable config is never read
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 9. WARNING in /tmp/appcfg2293558534073477148.tmp/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/jsp/pages/list_jsp.java (at line 37)
    [javac]     Object page = this;
    [javac]            ^^^^
    [javac] The local variable page is never read
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 9 problems (2 errors, 7 warnings)

Nov 5, 2012 8:43:06 AM org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler generateClass
SEVERE: Javac exception
Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:933)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:757)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler.generateClass(AntCompiler.java:226)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:1192)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1341)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC.main(LocalJspC.java:18)
Nov 5, 2012 8:43:06 AM org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler generateClass
SEVERE: Environment: Compile: javaFileName=/tmp/appcfg2293558534073477148.tmp/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/jsp/pages/list_jsp.java
classpath=/rhel5pdi/home/testuser/Desktop/softwares/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.3/appengine-java-sd
```

Comment: you might find these links useful. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2562
http://albertattard.blogspot.in/2009/08/jsp-compile-error-in-eclipse.html